# Why won't my initial climb to 500 feet AGL objective register?

Tags: microsoft-flight-simulator

When flying in free flight one of the earliest objectives is to stay in line with the runway and to perform the initial climb to 500 feet above ground level. Staying in line with the runway is an easy objective, and still completes even if you divert, but I've never satisfied the climb to 500 feet objective. Regardless of what altitude I'm flying at the objective remains.

I've tried to hold an altitude of 500 feet above the literal sea (taking off from Seattle means it isn't hard to find the ocean), or flying at drastically high altitudes of 20,000 feet AGL. Neither route completed the objective. What do I need to do to register the initial climb as complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug that has been patched in one of the game's many updates. Now when I fly this is no longer an issue. In free flight climbing to 500 feet AGL concludes the takeoff tips.